# adding CCPhysicsSprite to CCLayer cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to reorganize HelloWorld project in cocos2d to our needs.
The thing I did - made a class, which is inherent from `CCPhysicsSprite` and wanted to add it to `CCLayer` (`HelloWorldLayer`). But something goes wrong. According to debugger my instance is created, but I can't see it in the iOS emulator. Need your help and explanations.

HelloWorldLayer.h

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate,     GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
{
    CCTexture2D *spriteTexture_;    // weak ref
    b2World* world_;                    // strong ref
    GLESDebugDraw *m_debugDraw;     // strong ref
}
```

HelloWorldLayer.mm (only changed by me functions:)

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        // enable events

        self.touchEnabled = YES;
        self.accelerometerEnabled = YES;
        CGSize s = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        // init physics
        [self initPhysics];

        // create reset button
        //[self createMenu];

        //Set up sprite

//#if 1
//      // Use batch node. Faster
//      CCSpriteBatchNode *parent = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"blocks.png" capacity:100];
//      spriteTexture_ = [parent texture];
//#else
//      // doesn't use batch node. Slower
//      spriteTexture_ = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"blocks.png"];
//      CCNode *parent = [CCNode node];
//#endif
//      [self addChild:parent z:0 tag:kTagParentNode];
//      
//      
//      [self addNewSpriteAtPosition:ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2)];

        CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Tap screen" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
        [self addChild:label z:0];
        [label setColor:ccc3(0,0,255)];
        label.position = ccp( s.width/2, s.height-50);

        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) addNewSpriteAtPosition:(CGPoint)p
{
    CCLOG(@"Add sprite %0.2f x %02.f",p.x,p.y);
    if([self getChildByTag:kTagParentNode] == nil)
    {
        BloodRobotUnit *unit = [[BloodRobotUnit alloc] initWithOwner:world_ at:p];
        [self addChild:unit z:0 tag:kTagParentNode];
    }
}
```

And Creating unit: (header and mm file:)

```
@interface BloodRobotUnit : CCPhysicsSprite
{

    b2Body *body_;
    b2World *owner_;
}

-(id) initWithOwner:(b2World*)owner at:(CGPoint)pt;
```

mm:

```
-(id) initWithOwner:(b2World*)owner at:(CGPoint)pt
{
    if(self = [super initWithFile:@"blocks.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)])
    {
        owner_ = owner;
        //create body at position
        b2BodyDef bodyDef;
        bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.Set(pt.x/PTM_RATIO, pt.y/PTM_RATIO);
        body_ = owner->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

        // Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
        b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
        dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box

        // Define the dynamic body fixture.
        b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
        fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox;
        fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
        body_->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

        [self setB2Body: body_];
        [self setPosition:pt];
        return (self);

    }
return nil;
}
```

Where is my mistake? Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: is your addNewSpriteAtPosition is commented intentionally ? otherwise nothing will be added to the layer ? do you call it from somewhere else ?

Comment: yes
I commented it intentionally
addNewSpriteAtPosition is called from
`- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
`{`
`for( UITouch *touch in touches){`
`CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];` 
`location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];`
  
`[self addNewSpriteAtPosition: location];`
` }`
`}`

Comment: are you sure that the line adding the sprite is really reached ? and that the sprite is created successfully ?

Comment: yes, I call addNewSpriteAtPosition after touch and debugger is triggered inside of it

Comment: wait if you are using CCPhysicsSprite it already has a body and the position of the sprite is updated when the body position is updated. Try inheriting from CCSprite and see if it works.

Comment: This is where it failed:

`[self setB2Body: body_];`

I need body with physics - that is why I've inherited from CCPhysicSprite

Comment: Inherit from CCSprite gives me falling box and sprite left in position of touch

Comment: The CCPhysicsSprite also has a _ptmRatio property, try setting it with your PTM_RATIO definition. It probably uses it when converting box2d units to pixel units.

Comment: No luck :(
PTM_RATIO didn't do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was in setting position to self
Debugger showed that my texture was at position inf:inf

Code change to make everything work is the following:

in mm file of creating a CCPhysicsSprite iheriter do the following:

```
[self setB2Body: body_];
self.PTMRatio = PTM_RATIO;
//[self setPosition:CGPointMake(pt.x/PTM_RATIO, pt.y/PTM_RATIO)];
```

That is - you need to set only body position and set PTMRatio (thanx to @giorashc). Setting sprite texture is not necessary.